# Output is correct, why do I keep getting newline?

Tags: python

Complete the function definition to return the hours given minutes.

Sample output with input: `210.0`

```
3.5
```

```
def get_minutes_as_hours(orig_minutes):
    
    print(orig_minutes/60)

    minutes = float(input())

print(get_minutes_as_hours(minutes))
```

Comment: What newline are you talking about? You have two calls to `print` that each produce a newline, and your input is between the two calls.

Comment: In order for `print(get_minutes_as_hours(minutes))` to make any sense, the function being called needs to return a value to be printed.  But it doesn't - it prints the value itself, and implicitly returns `None`.

Comment: if you want print to not add a new line you can set ` print(orig_minutes/60, end=" ")
`

Comment: Doesn't this just go into infinite recursion?

Comment: Most likely the code is not indented like the original.  It would help to ensure your code is *exactly* what you are running, and specifying what your expect vs. actual results.

Comment: Judging by the output the op specifies, the last line must have been indented incorrectly

Comment: @Sayse More likely the last two lines, but let the OP fix their post.

Comment: `minutes = float(input())` is most likely without indentation

Comment: I see that instead of print the function needed to be a return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input is correct, but your function is wrong. Let's use your sample input, 210. Initially, it will print out 3.5. But then it will ask for minutes as an input. Since you have the input statement, it would appear that you are seeing a newline. I don't see the need for the last two lines:

```
def get_minutes_as_hours(orig_minutes):
    
    print(orig_minutes/60)
```

or if you want it to return instead of print:

```
def get_minutes_as_hours(orig_minutes):
    
    return orig_minutes/60
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean to write this.

```
def get_minutes_as_hours(orig_minutes):
   return orig_minutes/60

#--------------------
minutes = float(input())
print(get_minutes_as_hours(minutes))
```

Note

The indentation is only in def.

def has a return not a print

Answer (score 0):

reformat your code to this

```
def get_min_as_hours(original_min);
     return original_minutes/60
print(get_min_as_hours(minutes)
```